# What is that "on-hold" state?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I see the "on hold" state on some questions that would have been closed in the past.

What is this (new?) state, why was it introduced?

Can I vote to close in that state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There have been some changes to the close process. It's explained [in this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) and this [post on the main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons-bye-bye). And specifically, the "on hold" state is discussed at  [Every "close" has its thorn: replace "close" with "on hold" for the first five days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173497/every-close-has-its-thorn-replace-close-with-on-hold-for-the-first-five-d).

Basically, on-hold is a temporary state for closed questions, meant to not feel as nasty and to encourage actual improvement.

Comment: To clarify, since I'm not sure if "temporary state" is misleading, "on hold" is the new name for "closed". The point is to try and convey to people that closing isn't necessarily permanent if they can fix whatever is wrong with the question. There's no method to vote to close because the question *is* closed, we're just calling it something less severe

Comment: "On-hold" actually does become "closed" after a period, so it's not _just_ a new name.

Comment: Oh, I never noticed that

Comment: More precisely (Cc @MichaelMrozek), “on hold” means “closed less than 5 days ago” and “closed” means “on hold since more than 5 days”. Other than the name change, one thing happens at the 5-day mark: before that point, edits by the asker push the question to the reopen queue; after that point, only reopen votes do. Yes, it's obscure. No, I don't know why.